# Why is the Python-Selenium timeout error occurring in the loop?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

First of all, please understand that the entire code cannot be uploaded because it is a company file.

There are approximately 50 profiles, which are code that repeats login and logout sequentially.

For example, the first to eighth takes 20 seconds, while the ninth takes 60 seconds.
Also, in the 10th to 15th, it takes 20 seconds again, and in the 16th, there is a timeout error.
The order is random. There were times when it was the 16th, and times when it was the 20th.

I'd like to know why and how this happens. Please help.

p.s.
I've already used the wait.EC technique.

'''

```
    for i in range(len(ID)):
        toctoc = time.time()
        print(ID[i])

        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=option)
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

        driver.get('homepage')
        time.sleep(1)

        driver.execute_script("window.open('login page');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ID').send_keys(ID[i])  # ID
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'PW').send_keys(PW[i])  # PW
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'log-in').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)  # log-in
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(1)

        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.quit()
        time.sleep(1)
        print(time.time()-toctoc)
```

'''

Comment: don't mix implicit and explicit waits.  (Just use explicit... increase the timeout period if needed.  I don't see your explicit waits here... but just in case)  When you use both implicit and explicit, you'll have 2 competing polling loops.  I also see no reason to open a new tab, switch to it, and close it, but if you have to do this for some reason, you shouldn't rely on the order of the window handle array.  (It is not guaranteed...)  Instead get the current window handle... open the new tab... get all window handles, and iterate and choose the one that is not the current.

Comment: I would just like to repeat everything that @pcalkins said. In the official documentation it is said that you shouldn't mix implicit and explicit waits. In my opinion you even should never use implicit waits... 

As you did not provide the full details of the error, we just might speculate what went wrong. But you are definitely switching tabs in a wrong way. See the official Selenium documentation. The `window_handles` array will have random strings which will probably come alphabetically and it will randomly fail when trying to switch to the wrong tab.

Please do not use time.sleep(1)...